# to scan more than one barcodes at a time and it should come back to screen when the user is done with scan and store the result

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am developing a mobile barcode scanner application with ionic 3 and targeting for android and iOS devices, but now i am stuck here. 
In the app in which I have to scan a barcode and show it. The Initially requirement was for one product only but now as per the new requirement, the app should allow users to scan more than one barcodes at a time and it should come back to screen when the user is done with scan and store the result in existing div(array). 
I have managed to show for one product barcode scan result in a page using following code:-

```
scan()  
 {   
   this.options = {
   prompt : "Scan your barcode"
  }
   this.barcodeScanner.scan(this.options).then((barcodeData) => {   
   console.log(barcodeData);     
   this.scanData = barcodeData.text;   
   },(err) => {    
     console.log("Error occurred : " + err);    
  });    
  }
```

Could you please help me in that....how to to scan more than one barcodes at a time

Answer (score 0):

I would have scan return a promise with the result and store it in an array, then loop through the array to render the results.

Something like this:

```
scan(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    this.options = {
      prompt : "Scan your barcode"
    }
    this.barcodeScanner.scan(this.options).then((barcodeData) => {   
      resolve(barcodeData.text);   
    },(err) => {    
      reject(err);    
    });    
  })
}
```

use like:

```
const scans=[]

{
   scan().then((scanData)=>{
     scans.push(scanData);
     renderScanList(scans) //you can figure this part out
   })
   .catch(err=>{/*display error*/})
}
```